# Why there isn't a new line at the end of quoting a subshell and passing the results to echo?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, command-substitution

When I do `ls | grep png` the output of grep is:

```
2015-05-15-200203_1920x1080_scrot.png 
2015-05-16-025536_1920x1080_scrot.png
```

(filename,newline,filename,newline)

then, `echo $(ls | grep png)` outputs:

```
2015-05-15-200203_1920x1080_scrot.png 2015-05-16-025536_1920x1080_scrot.png
```

(filename,space from word splitting,filename,newline !!from echo!!)

That is all ok, but when I do this to prevent the word splitting: `echo "$(ls | grep png)"`, the output is:

```
2015-05-15-200203_1920x1080_scrot.png 
2015-05-16-025536_1920x1080_scrot.png
```

And my question is, where is the second newline (one should be from grep and one from echo)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's newline from `echo`, you can verify by using `echo -n` to suppress trailing newline:

```
echo -n "$(ls | grep png)"
```

[Command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) remove all trailing newlines, last newline was added by `echo`, `grep` has nothing to do here.

Comment: "Command substitution remove all trailing newlines" - thats it! Thank you